# Can't get rid of tabs and white space from a string php

Tags: php

I have tried just about every trick in the book, and the white space and tabs persist

I ran 'Recognize Text' in Adobe Acrobat to convert an image into a pdf where I could grab the text.

The text comes in, but there is a lot of what 'looks' like white space and tabs, but all the usual tricks won't get rid of them:

```
 $ltxt1 = str_replace("\x0B","",str_replace("\0","",str_replace(",","",str_replace(" ","",str_replace("\t","",str_replace("\n","~",$text))))));
```

and

```
$ltxt = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $ltxt1);
```

There is some issue related to the way I made the text renderable on the face of the pdf doc is my guess

Comment: Can you provide the text?

Comment: It would help if you look at the text with a hex viewer so you may see exactly what it contains. If it is really just tabs and white space `str_replace($yourtext,["\t",' '],'');` should work.

Answer (score 1):

the default function `trim` should work.

If you want to be sure then

```
$clean_string=preg_replace('/\s/g','',$dirty_string);
```

The `\s` flag is for [All Whitespace Characters](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) and the `g` should return all matches, not the first.

Otherwise you'll need to see what is *really* there and look in the hex or it could even be margin or padding that's pushing everything weirdly. Are there misplaced `<p>` or `<span>` tags that PDF renderers love to throw in with seemingly arbitrary formatting.